# How to show a popup on a first page visit? (working with Grails)

Tags: grails, popup

When user visits the website first time, popup window has to be shown to user suggesting to register to the newsletter and so on... I imagine that it is done with a cookie detection. What is the proper way of doing that with Grails? We use Spring Security Core plugin, but didn't find how it could help us.

Comment: You can use roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED  http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual.1273/guide/5%20Configuring%20Request%20Mappings%20to%20Secure%20URLs.html

Answer (score 0):

It probably makes sense to use a filter: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters

If you need to show the popup to all users(not just registered members) then the cookie/session is probably your only solution. 
In case that the popup is only displayed to logged in members you might use a filter similar to :

```
showPopupOnFirstLogin(controller:'*', action:'*') {
        before = {
            try{
                User user = springSecurityService.currentUser
                if (user?.mustGetNotification && !request.xhr){
                    //we ignore ajax requests
                    redirect(controller:"home", action:"showPopup")
                    return false
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                log.error "Failed to redirect", e
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: I need to show the popup to users, who are not registered members, just visiting site the first time.